# How to fix data features not applying in ajax responses for Jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How to fix data features such as data-role="button" not applying in ajax responses for Jquery mobile?

I call a PHP page that returns a set of data with a few buttons dynamically added based on the data set returned from the db. The problem is, the buttons returned in the response are missing the jquery mobile styling effects.

I do have buttons styling working properly on static pages, so jquery mobile is setup right.

Is this a limitation of the library or is there a work around?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact a duplicate, but here you go:

Use `.page()`

Take a look at my tutorial: http://jquerymobiledictionary.dyndns.org/faq.html

Comment: The comment in the link about .page() not being able to be applied to the same element twice, really helped.  Thanks!

Comment: I think I'll elaborate on that more in the FAQ, because it's a really common case.